# Error message: unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio 0.8.2 and debug on my Sony Xperia Z (USB).
I often get errors in Android Studio when I run/debug my app, like this:

```
[XTWiFi-PE] unknown deliver target [OS-Agent]
```

This happens for example if I add these two lines to the outside LinearLayout in activity_main.xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

These two lines enable that my EditText loses focus when the user touches the background of the app.
How can I get rid of this error? What does "unknown deliver target" mean?

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?